# sql cannot insert with numbers as column name

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, db2

I have a table called clients, in which i am trying to insert a new row.

The insert query is like so:

```
    var addclient = "insert into clients (NAME, EMAIL, PHONE_NUMBER, TRAINER_NAME, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) values ('" + name + "', '" + email + "', '" + phonenumber + "', '" + req.session.username + "', '" + monday + "', '" + tuesday + "', '" + wednesday + "', '" + thursday + "', '" + friday + "', '" + saturday + "', '" + sunday + "')";
```

however, when I run this, it gives me this error:

```
    Error: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7" was found following "UMBER, TRAINER_NAME,".  Expected tokens may include:  "<col_ref>".  SQLSTATE=42601
] {
  error: '[ibm_db] SQL_ERROR',
  sqlcode: -104,
  state: '42601'
}
```

but I don't see anything wrong my query. Any ideas? Do i have to do something unique since my column names are numbers?

Comment: Tried wrapping the numbers in single quotes?

Comment: @ArpitKhandelwal unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: Use backticks in MySQL to quote column names.

Comment: Why would you use numbers as column names in the first place?